# Why does the channel event readable keep firing in this code?

Tags: tcl

Could you tell me what in this code would cause the `chan event $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]` to repeatedly be fired after a socket has been reset?

I'm trying to keep the socket open on an extremely simple local server by resetting the socket to read again at the first line.

I'm not sure if it is the browser or the Tcl code. I flush the socket before sending each response using `chan flush $sock`; so, I don't think there should be any data left in the input buffer to fire the `readable` event.

Everything works fine until I stop using the application for a few minutes, and then procedure `ReadLine` is repeatedly invoked with a `state` of `1` but no data.

I included procedure `GetLexi` at the end because its the one I've been testing when this started occurring and, perhaps, I'm doing something wrong there and the browser doesn't know the response is complete. I should add also that it is called from with procedure `GetHandler` and should return back to the `switch` block and be reset.  I did test that the socket is reset after an invocation of `GetLexi`.

Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

```
proc ResetSock {sock} {
  global state
  set state($sock) {1}
  chan configure $sock -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
}; #close ResetSock

proc ClientConnect {sock client_ip client_port} {
   global state
   if {![info exists state($sock)]} {
     set state($sock) {1}; # 1 for first line; 2 for any other header line.
     chan configure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
   }
   chan event $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
}; #close ClientConnect

proc ReadLine {sock} {
  global state
  set sptr state($sock)
  set row [lindex [set $sptr] 0]

  if {[catch {gets $sock line} len]} {
      # Handle this error.
      return
    }

  if {$len == 0} {
      #According to Tclhttpd, in between requests, a row 1 and len 0 
      #combination can occur. There, it is ignored.
      if {$row == 2 } {
        switch [lindex [set $sptr] 1] {
          "POST" {
                  set post [PostHandler $sock [lindex [set $sptr] 3]]
                  puts stdout "Posted: $post"
                  ResetSock $sock
                 }
          "GET" {
                 GetHandler $sock [lindex [set $sptr] 2]
                 ResetSock $sock
                }
          default { CloseSock $sock }
         }
       }
  } elseif {$len > 0} {
      switch $row {
        1 {
           # First row of request.
           lassign [split [string trim $line]] op arg rest
           lappend $sptr $op $arg
           lset $sptr 0 0 2
          }
        2 {
           # Read headers.
          }
        default { }
      }
  } else {
      # Only other option for $len is a negative value;
      # thus, an error to be handled.
  }
}; #close ReadLine

proc GetLexi { nbr sock } {
  chan flush $sock
  set sql { select img_base64 from lexi_raw where strongs_no = $nbr }
  dbws eval $sql {
    set lexi [binary format a* "{\"lexi\":\"$img_base64\"}"]
  }

  set headers ""
  append headers "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
  append headers "Content-Type: application/json; charset: utf-8\n"
  append headers "Content-length: [string length $lexi]\n"
  append headers "Connection: Keep-Alive\n"
  puts $sock $headers

  chan configure $sock -translation binary
  puts $sock $lexi
}; #close GetLexi


set state(x) {}

if [catch {set listener [socket -server ClientConnect -myaddr 127.0.0.1 8000]}] {
  error "couldn't open listening socket"
}

vwait forever
catch {close $listener}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for the amount of data received in a packet to be not enough to complete a line. TCP hides most of the details, of course, but it remains entirely possible for the readable event to fire when a complete line is not available. As you've put the socket in non-blocking mode, that means that `gets` will do a zero length read (empty string written to `line`, `len` becomes 0); if the socket was blocking, the `gets` would block the thread until a complete line was available. You can also get zero-length reads if the channel is closed; detection of closure isn't very reliable with TCP (because networking is like that) but may happen. When the socket is closed, all reading from it in non-blocking mode results in zero-length results.

How do you distinguish these cases?

First, we check for end-of-stream:

```
if {[chan eof $sock]} {
    # It's gone; there's not much else you can do at this point except log it I guess
    close $sock
    return
}
```

Then we need to see if things are blocked, and if so, how much is buffered:

```
if {[chan blocked $sock]} {
    set bufferSize [chan pending input $sock]
    if {$bufferSize > 4096} {  # 4k is enough for most things
        # Line is too long; client not well-behaved…
        # You *might* send an error here.
        close $sock
        return
    }
}
```

If it's neither of those cases, we've actually read a line.

```
if {$len == 0} {
    # Empty line; end of HTTP header
} else {
    # etc.
}
```

Comment: In older code, `chan eof` is written `eof` and `chan blocked` is written `fblocked`. The `chan pending` command never had a single-word version.

Comment: Thank you. I think I see now what has been taking place. When the connection is left open and inactive for two minutes, the client sends the `eof` to close the connection. I assume then because it cannot be read in `proce ReadLine` since it is not a line, the `readable` event keeps firing repeatedly and blows up my machine.  If the connection is closed after receiving `eof` then there is no issue; and the next request is made on a new socket. Thank you very much for all the information and help.